# What to use when querying a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Should I be using mysqli or mysql when querying a database? I know you can use both and I'm unsure about which one is the best to use. I know I have to make a login system using mysqli as its more secure. Does it matter which one?

Comment: http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/blog/mysql-vs-mysqli/

Answer (score 0):

Between the two options you have offered Definitely use `mysqli`, the `mysql` functions have been deprecated from php

Please refer to **php documentation** -
*  http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Another alternative is to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) when connecting to a database.

Answer (score 0):

mysql is deprecated. That means it will cease to work some time in the future. So you are strongly encouraged to use mysqli or pdo.
I Suggest reading up on that matter on php.net.